# MATLAB Guide tries to run nonexistent function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I was making a GUI using GUIDE in Matlab. My computer froze and Matlab crashed. When I went to reopen GUIDE, I get the following error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'badfcn_CreateFcn'.

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in quick_gui (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)quick_gui('badfcn_CreateFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

However, this function `badfcn_CreateFcn` does not exist anywhere in my gui.m file. There is also no object in my gui with this tag or description.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does this happen when you open the .fig file with GUIDE or when you try to launch your GUI?

Comment: Both. extra characters because SO requires a minimum character count.

Comment: have you tried to create the function in quick_gui.m and setting a breack point? In the hObject you should be able to see what is calling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the tag of a ui object had been changed, but the Callback and Create functions were using the old tag name. This won't be apparent in the object browser. Since I have everything in panels, I did what @marco wassmer recommended and created the function with a breakpoint. This is how I found that the object was residing in Panel X. I went through all objects in Panel X and sure enough, one of them was using the badfcn tag for the Callback and Create functions even though the tag name was different.